# Stepwise regression in R with model constraints

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

I have estimated a gravity model for some international flow than uses data on origin countries `x*_o`, destination countries `x*_d`, and a set ofdistance variables `x*`. I now want to see if I can find a more concise model using stepwise model selection. My data looks something like this:

```
set.seed(450)
data <- data.frame(dep = rnorm(20, 6, 2),
                   x1_o = rnorm(20, 0, 1),
                   x1_d = rnorm(20, 5, 3),
                   x2_o = rnorm(20, 5, 3),
                   x2_d = rnorm(20, 5, 3),
                   x3_o = rnorm(20, 5, 3),
                   x3_d = rnorm(20, 5, 3),
                   x4 = rnorm(20, 5, 3),
                   x5 = rnorm(20, 5, 3),
                   x6 = rnorm(20, 5, 3))
```

Fit a linear model and do stepwise regression:

```
lm_fit <- lm(dep ~ ., data = data)
step_fit <- step(lm_fit, direction = "both")
summary(step_fit)
```

Results:

```
Call:
lm(formula = dep ~ x1_d + x2_d + x3_o + x3_d + x4 + x6, data = data)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-1.962 -1.003  0.213  0.550  1.955 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   9.4525     1.5384   6.144 3.52e-05 ***
x1_d         -0.1615     0.1141  -1.416  0.18039    
x2_d         -0.8532     0.2105  -4.053  0.00137 ** 
x3_o         -0.1334     0.1011  -1.320  0.20969    
x3_d          0.2332     0.1319   1.768  0.10055    
x4            0.2830     0.1304   2.170  0.04914 *  
x6           -0.1729     0.1123  -1.539  0.14776    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.411 on 13 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.595, Adjusted R-squared:  0.4081 
F-statistic: 3.183 on 6 and 13 DF,  p-value: 0.0379
```

As you can see `step` dropped the `x1` and `x2` variable for the origin countries, but kept them for the destination countries. What I want to achieve is that `step` always either keeps or drops a variable for both origin and destination countries. For example, `x1_o` and `x1_d` should be either both in or both out.

Is this possible in R? The `scope` argument provides the option to impose some constraints on the model selection, but I'm not sure it is possible to do what I want using that option.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define each of the paired columns as a factor with `nrow(data)` levels and 2 columns equal to the origin and destination.  For any such factor, that will force it to either keep both columns or reject both columns.  Using the data in the Note at the end (which is the same as in the question except the random seed has been modified so that the answer is a mix of factors and remaining columns:

```
nr <- nrow(data)
data2 <- transform(data, 
  x1 = C(factor(1:nr), cbind(x1_o, x1_d), 2),
  x2 = C(factor(1:nr), cbind(x2_o, x2_d), 2),
  x3 = C(factor(1:nr), cbind(x3_o, x3_d), 2))

fm <- lm(dep ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6, data2)
dim(model.matrix(fm)) # check dimensions of model matrix
step(fm)
```

### Note

```
set.seed(13)
data <- data.frame(dep = rnorm(20, 6, 2),
                   x1_o = rnorm(20, 0, 1),
                   x1_d = rnorm(20, 5, 3),
                   x2_o = rnorm(20, 5, 3),
                   x2_d = rnorm(20, 5, 3),
                   x3_o = rnorm(20, 5, 3),
                   x3_d = rnorm(20, 5, 3),
                   x4 = rnorm(20, 5, 3),
                   x5 = rnorm(20, 5, 3),
                   x6 = rnorm(20, 5, 3))
```